# Buying tickets for New York Yankees game

Tags: tickets, new-york-city, sports-events

I'll be in NYC on 13th September and was hoping to take my daughter to a Yankees game (we're Brits and are looking for the quintessential American day out!).  They are playing the Toronto Blue Jays. I seek advice on tickets:

Do we buy them on-line from the UK with all the currency hassle?

Or can we wait until the day of the game and buy them at the stadium?

Is it likely to be a sell out?

Lastly, is it safe to buy via StubHub?

Comment: Should be a good day out- currently the two top teams in AL East. I've used Stubhub for a SF Giants game with no problems, no currency hassles with credit cards. The official ticket office should be your first stop. BTW, if you're not fairly familiar with baseball you might want to spend a bit of time learning a few of the subtleties. I say this because a couple of Commonwealth colleagues claimed to find it  very boring.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I agree with the familiarity aspect. I had the inverse problem of growing up with baseball, and I found the nuances of a cricket game incomprehensible at first. Fortunately, my traveling companion patiently fielded all of my newcomer questions, which made the game extremely enjoyable. If you can find someone willing to explain the baseball score-keeping (originally based on cricket and invented by an Englishman) real-time during the game, it will definitely enrich your experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options to buy tickets:

1. Online via the official website ahead of time. This will be the safest option and allows you to pick exactly the seats you want. When paying via credit card there isn't any real inconvenience dealing with currency conversion.
2. Online via StubHub. I have used StubHub many times and find the site reliable and safe. Make sure you buy tickets that are available via PDF so you can print them before you leave on your trip. Usually StubHub is a good resource for sold out games; if a game still has tickets available I prefer the official channels.
3. At the stadium the day of. This is an option only if the game isn't sold out. There is no benefit over advance purchase (aside from maybe saving a few dollars over the online purchase), so I don't recommend this.
4. From scalpers at the stadium. This should be the last resort, as prices are unpredictable and inventory unknown.

Given that you are planning this game into your trip ahead of time, I highly recommend you purchase tickets from the official website in far as advance as possible. This will allow you to choose the exact seats you like and give you peace of mind for your trip.

Comment: Just bought the tickets.  Now I need to look up the rules of baseball!

Comment: @SAL You can download the [2015 Major League Baseball Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2015/official_baseball_rules.pdf) as a PDF document or purchase them as in a [small paperback](http://www.amazon.com/Official-Rules-Major-League-Baseball/dp/1629370754). There is also a MLB At Bat phone app that might help you to understand the play-by-play real-time during the game.

Comment: @SAL Great! Have fun!